# Dynamic nested serializer field Django REST Framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to have a serializer of a Parent model, with a nested serializer as a field, being different regarding another string field.

For example, if the `registry_type` field is equal to `intra` I want to use `_IntraRegistrySerializer` to serialize/deserialize the `registry_data` field, but if `registry_type` is equal to `slack`, I want to use `_SlackRegistrySerializer` for the same field.

I managed to have the serialization working doing this:

```py
class RegistrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        if isinstance(instance, IntraRegistry):
            data["registry_type"] = "intra"
            data["registry_data"] = _IntraRegistrySerializer(instance=instance).data
        if isinstance(instance, SlackRegistry):
            data["registry_type"] = "slack"
            data["registry_data"] = _SlackRegistrySerializer(instance=instance).data
        return data

    class Meta:
        # `Registry` being the parent model of both `IntraRegistry` and `SlackRegistry`
        model = Registry
        fields = ["id", "description"]
```

But it only does half of what I would like to do.

I tried overloading methods, using `SerializerMethodField`, and even though I keep on searching and reading the doc I can't manage to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This does seem like a good `SerializerMethodField` case:

```py
class RegistrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    registry_type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    registry_data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_registry_type(self, obj):
        if isinstance(instance, IntraRegistry):
            return "intra"
        if isinstance(instance, SlackRegistry):
            return "slack"

    def get_registry_data(self, obj):
        if isinstance(instance, IntraRegistry):
            return _IntraRegistrySerializer(instance=obj, context=self.context).data
        if isinstance(instance, SlackRegistry):
            return _SlackRegistrySerializer(instance=obj, context=self.context).data

    class Meta:
        # `Registry` being the parent model of both `IntraRegistry` and `SlackRegistry`
        model = Registry
        fields = ["id", "description", "registry_type", "registry_data"]
```

The above is the implementation of the serializer method fields and should work since both of the registries inherit from `Registry`.

You may still need to tweak it to your needs. One difference compared to the current implementation is that the `registry_type` and `registry_data` will now always be present. They'll be `null` if this is a `Registry` object type or some other child type not handled here.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helped me improve the serialization part! However I am still stuck at the deserialization part... Well I managed to do it, but I lose a lot of the validation features... I don't feel like I am doing it well